# How to input multiple csv files in logstash (Elasicsearch). please give one simple example.

Tags: logstash

How to input multiple csv files in logstash (Elasicsearch). please give one simple example.

if I have five  csv files in one folder & still new files may get created in same location so how can I process all new files also in logstash.

Answer (score 0):

change in file path only. ( path => "/home/mahadev/data/*.csv)

So now we can able to read all csv files inside the data folder. if any new csv comes then it will get reflect into logstash.

Please note: the above file path we need to put in logstash's conf file. if you are new then please read about logstash configration file then read this.

Comment: the above answer works in linux but not Windows. Please suggest appropriate answer.

Comment: For Windows you would just have to use the correct path to the folder where the csv files are.